# How to assign return value to constrained generic type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type a function with which takes optional properties in common, and requires properties that are missing based on the passed in generic type.

```
type Diff<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T
type DiffTypes<T, U> = { [Key in Diff<keyof T, keyof U>]: T[Key] }

interface Common {
    name: string
}

interface One {
    name: string
    one: 1
}

interface Two {
    name: string
    two: 2
}

interface Three {
    name: string
    three: 3
}

type Numbers = One | Two | Three

const test = <T extends Numbers>(obj: Partial<Common> & DiffTypes<T, Common>): T => ({name: 'Default', ...obj})
```

I'm getting

```
Type '{ name: string; } & Partial<Common> & DiffTypes<T, Common>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Diff%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20U%20%3F%20never%20%3A%20T%0D%0Atype%20DiffTypes%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BKey%20in%20Diff%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20keyof%20U%3E%5D%3A%20T%5BKey%5D%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Common%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20One%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20one%3A%201%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Two%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20two%3A%202%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Three%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20three%3A%203%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Numbers%20%3D%20One%20%7C%20Two%20%7C%20Three%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20Numbers%3E(obj%3A%20Partial%3CCommon%3E%20%26%20DiffTypes%3CT%2C%20Common%3E)%3A%20T%20%3D%3E%20(%7Bname%3A%20'Default'%2C%20...obj%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Edit: I also want to make sure the generic type is either One | Two | Three

Is this possible? Is there a better way to think about this?

Comment: what does this `<T extends Number>` in last line mean? what are you doing here?

Comment: Your return value should conform to interface `T`, which is not defined anywhere :) This is what TS compiler tells you.

Please rethink what you want to achieve with this definition on the last line.

Comment: With `<T extends Number>` I want to make sure the generic type is either One | Two | Three

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR: Typescript doesn't know the difference between missing and undefined properties**

The problem is actually the `Partial<Common>` in the `obj` argument type which actually gets interpreted as:

```
{
  name?: string | undefined
}
```

Typescript can't distinguish between `missing` and `undefined` which therefore makes:

```
test<One>({name: undefined})
```

valid as far as the argument type is concerned. Passing a `name` of `undefined` would overwrite the default name and would not meet the requirements for the return type -- resulting in the error message.

The relevant issue tracking this can be found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195

**My Solution**
Until typescript can make this distinction I opted to cast the overrides object.

```
const test = <T extends Numbers>(
  obj: Partial<Common> & DiffTypes<T, Common>,
): T => ({ name: 'Default', ...(obj as Common) })
```

with a big fat disclaimer to anyone who uses it that undefined should never be passed. Which works in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean:

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = {[P in Diff<keyof T, K>]: T[P]};
type Optional<T, U extends keyof T = keyof T> = Omit<T, U> & Partial<Pick<T, U>>;

const test = <T extends Numbers>(missing: Optional<T, keyof Common>): Common & typeof missing => ({
    name: 'Default',
    ...missing
});
```

Usage:

```
test<One>({ one: 1 });
test<One>({ one: 1, name: 'whooo' });
test<Two>({ two: 2 });
test<Three>({ three: 3 });

test<One>({ name: 'Bob' }) // Error
test<One>({ two: 2 })      // Error
```

Comment: I would like to be able to also override the common property. In this case `name`